# c - pjsip account registration with outbound_proxy values throws "Invalid outbound proxy URI"

Tags: pjsip

I am trying to perform SIP REGISTER to P-CSCF using pjsip C-library.
I have created, Initialized and Started pjsua.
I have also created transport using pjsua_transport_create.
When I use outbound proxy as below. I receive

> Invalid outbount proxy URI

the outbound proxy:

```
pjsua_config sua_config;
pjsua_config_default(&sua_config);
sua_config.cb.on_incoming_call = &sua_on_incoming_call;
sua_config.cb.on_call_media_state = &sua_on_call_media_state;
sua_config.cb.on_call_state = &sua_on_call_state;
sua_config.outbound_proxy_cnt = 1;
sua_config.outbound_proxy[0] = pj_str("172.40.21.20");
sua_config.require_100rel=1;
```

If I comment outbound proxy and config only proxy in account config. Then I receive

> Invalid route URI 172.40.21.20.

account config:

```
pjsua_acc_config account_config;
pjsua_acc_config_default(&account_config);
account_config.id = pj_str("\"Demo user\" <sip:demouser@domainname");
account_config.reg_uri = pj_str("sip:domainname");
account_config.cred_count = 1;
account_config.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str("domainname");
account_config.cred_info[1].scheme = pj_str("digest");
account_config.cred_info[2].username = pj_str("demouser");
account_config.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_DIGEST;
account_config.cred_info[0].data = pj_str("testdemouser");
account_config.reg_use_proxy=3;
account_config.require_100rel=1;
account_config.proxy_cnt=1;
account_config.proxy[0]=pj_str("172.40.21.20");
```

Questions:

1. Is  assigning URL using pj_str the correct way?
2. Do I need to enter both pjsua_config and pjsua_acc_config with proxy values?

Comment: You need to add port also.. i think format for adding outbound proxy is "sip:ip:port"

Comment: 1. What URL are you talking about? Can you please clarify?
2. Your proxy has to be configured in account configuration with full proxy as well as port.

Answer (score 0):

I missed prefixing "sip:" to the ip address. @nandhakumar is right.

Since I figured out myself, I did not vote @nandha